# webpack 4 using nodejs api - not creating vendors chunk

Tags: node.js, api, webpack, build

I have the following in my webpack 4 configuration:

```
 optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

running webpack from the command line, I see three files in the generated output:

- main.js
- vendors.js
- runtime.js

However, on the server side I am using gulp and webpack 4 nodejs api to build the front end pragmatically:

```
function buildFrontEnd(config) {
  return function buildTheFrontEnd(cb) {
    webpack(config,cb);
  };
}
```

This results in the webpack build output being different from the command line output, missing the vendors.js file (as if running webpack pragmatically ignores splitChunks). Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer, turns out @babel/preset-env and @babel/preset-react had to be installed on the server and the build error wasn't propagating through gulp.